# What's the meaning of IO actions within pure functions?

Tags: haskell, monads

I thought that in principle Haskell's type system would forbid calls to impure functions (i.e. `f :: a -> IO b`) from pure ones, but today I realized that by calling them with `return` they compile just fine. In this example:

```
h :: Maybe ()
h = do
    return $ putStrLn "???"
    return ()
```

`h` works in the `Maybe` monad, but it's a pure function nevertheless. Compiling and running it simply returns `Just ()` as one would expect, without actually doing any I/O. I think Haskell's laziness puts the things together (i.e. `putStrLn`'s return value is not used - and can't since its value constructors are hidden and I can't pattern match against it), but why is this code legal? Are there any other reasons that makes this allowed?

As a bonus, related question: in general, is it possible to forbid at all the execution of actions of a monad from within other ones, and how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IO actions are first-class values like any other; that's what makes Haskell's IO so expressive, allowing you to build higher-order control structures (like `mapM_`) from scratch. Laziness isn't relevant here,<sup>1</sup> it's just that you're not actually *executing* the action. You're just constructing the value `Just (putStrLn "???")`, then throwing it away.

`putStrLn "???"` *existing* doesn't cause a line to be printed to the screen. By itself, `putStrLn "???"` is just a *description* of some IO that could be done to cause a line to be printed to the screen. The only execution that happens is executing `main`, which you constructed from other IO actions, or whatever actions you type into GHCi. For more information, see the [introduction to IO](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_IO).

Indeed, it's perfectly conceivable that you might want to juggle about `IO` actions inside `Maybe`; imagine a function `String -> Maybe (IO ())`, which checks the string for validity, and if it's valid, returns an IO action to print some information derived from the string. This is possible precisely because of Haskell's first-class IO actions.

But a monad has no ability to execute the actions of another monad unless you give it that ability.

<sup>1</sup> Indeed, `` h = putStrLn "???" `seq` return () `` doesn't cause any IO to be performed either, even though it forces the evaluation of `putStrLn "???"`.

Comment: How can I give a monad the ability to execute actions from another one then, by giving it the possibility to pattern match against the values it contains?

Comment: By writing methods that convert one monad into another, or do some execution.  `Control.Monad.ST.stToIO` converts an `ST` computation into an `IO` computation, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the "is just a description of io". That settles the io mystery for me, without even caring about monads.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was wondering what might happen to a function like `f :: (Int -> IO ()) -> Int`

Answer (score 5):

Let's desugar!

```
h = do return (putStrLn "???"); return ()
-- rewrite (do foo; bar) as (foo >> do bar)
h = return (putStrLn "???") >> do return ()
-- redundant do
h = return (putStrLn "???") >> return ()
-- return for Maybe = Just
h = Just (putStrLn "???") >> Just ()
-- replace (foo >> bar) with its definition, (foo >>= (\_ -> bar))
h = Just (putStrLn "???") >>= (\_ -> Just ())
```

Now, what happens when you evaluate `h`?* Well, for Maybe,

```
(Just x) >>= f = f x
Nothing  >>= f = Nothing
```

So we pattern match the first case

```
f x
-- x = (putStrLn "???"), f = (\_ -> Just ())
(\_ -> Just ()) (putStrLn "???")
-- apply the argument and ignore it
Just ()
```

Notice how we never had to perform `putStrLn "???"` in order to evaluate this expression.

*n.b. It is somewhat unclear at which point "desugaring" stops and "evaluation" begins. It depends on your compiler's inlining decisions. Pure computations could be evaluated entirely at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the desugaring. Very useful for a newcomer. I dont understand why so many tutorials start with the sugar in. First have dinner, then desert.